# Why Che server is unable to ping your workspace?

Tags: eclipse, docker, eclipse-che

I have install Eclipse Che on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I m connecting from a remote computer to my eclipse che with an external IP.
I have opened port 8000,8080,9500,9000 on my ubuntu firewall.

I changed my ports to avoid tomcat conflict and ip to be able to redirect the ip

> docker run -it --rm -p 9000:9500 -e CHE_PORT=9500 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ~/EclipseChe:/data -e CHE_HOST=192.168.1.32 eclipse/che start

```
INFO: (che start): Preflight checks
WARNING: No swap limit support
mem (1.5 GiB): [OK]
disk (100 MB): [OK]
port 9500 (http): [AVAILABLE]
conn (browser => ws): [OK]
conn (server => ws): [OK]


INFO: (che start): Starting containers...
INFO: (che start): Services booting...
INFO: (che start): Server logs at "docker logs -f che-9500"
^CERROR: (che start): Timeout waiting for server. Run "docker logs che-9500" to inspect.
```

I can launch che, but when I create a blank workspace I have this error

```
Could not start workspace wksp-onaa. Reason: Start of environment
'default' failed. Error: Timeout. The Che server is unable to ping
your workspace. This implies a network configuration issue, workspace
boot failure, or an unusually slow workspace boot.
```

I have tried to:

- disable firewall using `sudo ufw disable`
- change the times max `che.workspace.agent.dev.max_start_time_ms=600000` and `che.agent.dev.max_start_time_ms=600000`
- run another web application `docker run -d -p 32829:80 nginx`. `curl - v 192.168.1.32:32829` gives me the welcome page
- The info --network gives : 

  INFO: (che cli): 5.17.0 - using docker 17.07.0-ce / native
  WARN: (che cli): 'CHE_HOST=192.168.1.32' from command line overriding 
  'CHE_HOST=172.17.0.1' from che.env
  INFO:
  INFO: ---------------------------------------
  INFO: --------   CONNECTIVITY TEST   --------
  INFO: ---------------------------------------
  INFO: (che network): eclipse/che-ip:5.17.0: 192.168.1.32
  INFO: (che network): Browser => Workspace Agent (localhost): Connection failed
  INFO: (che network): Browser => Workspace Agent (192.168.1.32): Connection 
  succeeded
  INFO: (che network): Server  => Workspace Agent (External IP): Connection 
  succeeded
  INFO: (che network): Server  => Workspace Agent (Internal IP): Connection 
  succeeded

When I run a worspace, here is the log : 

[che_unable_ping_workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0bs1.jpg)

INFO: ---------------------------------------
INFO: ---------   LAUNCHER INFO  ------------
INFO: ---------------------------------------
INFO:
INFO: ---------  PLATFORM INFO  -------------
INFO: DOCKER_INSTALL_TYPE       = native
WARNING: No swap limit support                
INFO: DOCKER_HOST_OS            = Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
INFO: DOCKER_HOST_IP            = 172.17.0.1
INFO: DOCKER_HOST_EXTERNAL_IP   = not set
INFO: DOCKER_DAEMON_VERSION     = 17.07.0-ce
INFO:
INFO:
INFO: --------- CHE INSTANCE LIST  ----------
INFO: ----  CURRENT COMMAND LINE OPTIONS  ---
INFO: CHE_VERSION               = nightly
INFO: CHE_DATA                  = /home/user/che
INFO: CHE_CONF                  = not set
INFO: CHE_ASSEMBLY              = not set
INFO: CHE_PORT                  = 8080
INFO: CHE_HOST_IP               = 172.17.0.1
INFO: CHE_RESTART_POLICY        = no
INFO: CHE_USER                  = root
INFO: CHE_LOG_LEVEL             = info
INFO: CHE_DEBUG_SERVER          = false
INFO: CHE_DEBUG_SERVER_PORT     = 8000
INFO: CHE_HOSTNAME              = localhost
INFO: CHE_SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME = che-server
INFO: CHE_SERVER_IMAGE_NAME     = codenvy/che-server

Che Diagnostic :
Websockets
No reply of websocket test after 5 seconds. Websocket is failing to connect to ws://17x.xxx.xxx.xx:9000/api/ws
Che try to connect from my external IP adress???

Test connection from browser to workspace agent by using Workspace Agent IP
Unable to perform call on http://192.168.1.32:32771/api: Status -1, 
statusText:/null
Please, I need help

```
OS and version:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (not a VM)
```

Comment: What is the output of `docker run -it --rm -p 9000:9500 -e CHE_PORT=9500 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ~/EclipseChe:/data -e CHE_HOST=192.168.1.32 eclipse/che info --network`

Comment: Also try to start the server using this `docker run -it --rm -e CHE_PORT=9500 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ~/EclipseChe:/data -e CHE_HOST=192.168.1.32 eclipse/che start`. Connect to your workspace at `http://192.168.1.32:9500`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have had the result in my previous question and a picture of a workspace test. I have tried your command line but I got the same issue. have you another idea?

Comment: Do `sudo rm -rf ~/EclipseChe` and then run the command `docker run -it --rm -e CHE_PORT=9500 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v ~/EclipseChe:/data -e CHE_HOST=192.168.1.32 eclipse/che start`. You need to delete the old config that got generated

Comment: I did, same result. do you want me to edit the che.env ?

Comment: Try using minimal setup for now `docker run -it --rm -e CHE_PORT=8080 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e CHE_HOST=192.168.1.32 eclipse/che start`. And use port 8080 this time

Comment: I remoded the EclipseChe folder and tried with port 8080 as you suggest but get the same error on workspace creation. with the minima, I have  : We could not detect a location to save data.

Comment: Setup worked at my end, so not sure what could be wrong. Mine also was 16.04 LTS

Comment: too bad , thanks anyway. I add some information in the question.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I am in ssh remote mode...

Comment: Can you add `ifconfig` output. It may help to understand IP resolution problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the ephemeral port range too since workspace agent ports are chosen from that range.